# Create a custom Case phone field that is a copy of the Contact.Phone field

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I want to add a custom field to the Case object that is searchable by SOSL "FIND ... IN PHONE FIELDS" (ie it must be of type PHONE), and contains a copy of the Phone field in the Contact that is pointed at by Case.ContactId. I would like it ideally to stay up to date if the value in the Contact record is changed.

I have tried creating a custom Formula field, but it doesn't allow me to return 'PHONE' type from the formula.

I have tried creating a custom Phone field, into which one may enter a formula, but I haven't found a syntax that pulls the data from Contact.Phone, which is what I want. I tried simply entering

```
Contact.Phone
```

in the formula editor, and I get

```
Error: Field Contact does not exist. Check spelling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a `Contact_Phone__c` field on Case (type = Phone).
2. Make a new workflow rule on Case, condition `ISBLANK(Contact_Phone__c) || ISCHANGED(ContactId)`.
3. Attach to this workflow a new field update with formula `Contact.Phone` (no idea why it didn't want to work for you.
4. Remember to activate the workflow.

It's still a bit naive as it won't kick in when you change the Contact's phone (it won't cascade down to all cases). You could read about cross-object workflows for that but I suspect you'll need a trigger...

Comment: Thank you - it looks as if a trigger plus a set of workflow field updates will solve this. I am going to make the trigger update a single autoincrement field which will run the workflow - that should keep all the actual field copying point-and-click, thus more maintainable.